# Our source of information was the spies captured during the raid. - Why is it ok for "spies" to be plural when subject/verb is singular?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> Our **source of information was** the **spies** captured during the raid.

Subject singular, helping verb singular then how come **spies** being plural fits in here?

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no requirement in English that the object of a sentence match the number of the subject or the verb.

For example...

> I have cats.

The subject is singular, the verb is singular but the object is plural.

Yes, "spies" are the "source of information"... and you can rephrase it as such:

> The spies captured during the raid were our source of information.

Now the subject and verb are plural but the object is singular.

---

So, if you have several spies, why is it only one "source of information"... because they are being treated as a single group of people, and that group makes up a single "source". This is a choice by the author of the sentence.

It's perfectly acceptable to consider each spy captured during the raid as a single source:

> Our sources of information were the spies captured during the raid.
>   The spies captured during the raid were our sources of information.

Both of these are fine, they're just not what the author chose, though I personally prefer the original in this case.